# Publish an Android app with MAUI warnings for deobfuscation and native code

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I have created a `NET8` `MAUI` application. I published my app on Google Play but I have 2 warnings:

> There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size.

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend that you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug.

What is the correct way to publish the app from Visual Studio? I'm using the *Ad hoc* distribution.

Comment: I found the related issue on the Github you can check this issue about the [Debug symbols upload on Google Play Console for better crash information](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5378).

Comment: The linked issue is for Xamarin from 2021. The solution does not seem to have carried forward to Visual studio 2022 in 2024. :-(