# NET8 MAUI and Visual Studio 17.8.6: code shrinker for Android disappeared

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, maui

More than 20 days ago, I created a post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782155/publish-an-android-app-with-maui-warnings-for-deobfuscation-and-native-code) because when I uploaded my NET8 MAUI application to the Google Play console, I get some warnings

> There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you
> use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will
> make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug. Using R8/proguard
> can help reduce app size.

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug
> symbols. We recommend that you upload a symbol file to make your
> crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug.

After upgrading Visual Studio today, I noticed that there is no more option for the `Dex Compiler` or `Code shrinker` in the project or in the `AndroidManifest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, and select Properties to find the setting about the Code shrinker:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to the official document about [Options for the Android platform in the .net maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/visual-studio-properties?view=net-maui-8.0#options).